# printing values of an array of integers

Tags: java, arrays, int

When printing the values within an array of type int. For some reason it keeps printing the last value of list

```
public class Algorithm {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
int list[] = {10, 9, 8, 7, 6};


public void printList(){

for (int x: list ) {
        System.out.print(x);

}
```

}

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Algorithm alg = new Algorithm();
    alg.printList();


}
```

}

I get 66666. How can I print all the values of the array?

Comment: I don't see a `getArray()` method? Is this code even valid?

Comment: The current code doesn't compile and doesn't provide exact info to us to spot the error

Comment: Also `printList()` is never called and is missing the closing `}`

Comment: Oh sorry to confuse there. Basically that's the exact copy of the method I have above just like printList()

Comment: The code works as intended, it's just the indentation that's screwed up. If this is the code you use and get a wrong result, something's gone very wrong with your JVM.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the problem was somewhere else. Unlikely to help future visitors.

Comment: To be honest, I modified it directly on here that's why that happened. Or else the syntax and indentation etc are all fine on my program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI, there's a method for printing arrays - don't reinvent the wheel!

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list));
```

Don't forget to import the `Arrays` class at the beginning:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
```

Comment: @JP24 then the problem is with the array, the above code will correctly print _any_ array, if it prints `66666`, it's because that's what the array contains. Are you sure that you're passing the correct array?